# zeppelin can't communicate with Cassandra (docker, windows 10 host)

Tags: windows, docker, cassandra

I'm using a docker version of zeppelin and another docker version of
cassandra.  They both works well separately but when I try to run some
basic cassandra command in a zeppelin notebook , I get an error :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler.generateSettings(ScalaCompiler.scala:123)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler.(ScalaCompiler.scala:59)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler$.create(ScalaCompiler.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.createCompiler(TemplateEngine.scala:231)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler$lzycompute(TemplateEngine.scala:221)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler(TemplateEngine.scala:221)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:757)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:699)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:419)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:413)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:471)
>     at
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.layout(TemplateEngine.scala:573)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.(DisplaySystem.scala:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.(DisplaySystem.scala)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.EnhancedSession.(EnhancedSession.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.InterpreterLogic.(InterpreterLogic.scala:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter.open(CassandraInterpreter.java:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:390)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> ----------------------- INFORMATION :
>
> **On the docker network :**  both containers are running in a custom bridge based network.
>
> **command to run zeppelin :**  docker run --name zeppelin -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 --network=flyingCassandra -v /d/*Gdrive*/*dockerShipyards*/volumes/zeppelin/:/c/usr/zeppelin/
>   zeppelin
>
> **Content of the bat file to launch the cassandra container :**  powershell -Command "& {docker run --name myCassandra -p
>   127.0.0.1:9042:9042 -p 127.0.0.1:9160:9160 -d --network=flyingCassandra -v d:/*GDrive*/*dockerShipyards*/volumes/myCassandra:/usr/cassandra
>   cassandra:3.0;}"
>
> **Resulting network**  PS D:_GDrive__dockerShipyards_> docker network inspect flyingCassandra [
>       {
>           "Name": "flyingCassandra",
>           "Id": "0250fb1cbe9b3f83722975a05dcc7d97aafaa5b68e40d056d766277d078ddd67",
>           "Scope": "local",
>           "Driver": "bridge",
>           "EnableIPv6": false,
>           "IPAM": {
>               "Driver": "default",
>               "Options": {},
>               "Config": [
>                   {
>                       "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
>                       "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
>                   }
>               ]
>           },
>           "Internal": false,
>           "Containers": {
>               "0a07c4e94350ac04d205fd08b57fc538b58b4fa309274871265ceecf13c2945d": {
>                   "Name": "myCassandra",
>                   "EndpointID": "687701ecf617ef0f6df64553510577c6690058e253f00e72b33ce628bc76eee2",
>                   "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
>                   "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
>                   "IPv6Address": ""
>               },
>               "34d3225eb7d2974ff83a2d6fe437167110d13af67bca8d415ddf74e63faf6327": {
>                   "Name": "Cassinterface",
>                   "EndpointID": "8921e5b970bb40983cec6e1ff5a222beb94382a03a80e0d8e4271d17f270e0d2",
>                   "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
>                   "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
>                   "IPv6Address": ""
>               },
>               "904b3fe78a64d61a6e1ee07a7236483efbb9e2d9eed81347a035f4ed9056b143": {
>                   "Name": "zeppelin",
>                   "EndpointID": "436c5a749bda9b12b78bd5f6564d483d2f611345dff48c4ffc8cdc841573bda0",
>                   "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
>                   "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
>                   "IPv6Address": ""
>               }
>           },
>           "Options": {},
>           "Labels": {}
>       } ]
>        PS D:_GDrive__dockerShipyards_> docker ps
>       CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                      CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES 
>   34d3225eb7d2        cassandra:3.0       "/docker-entrypoint.s" 35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp    Cassinterface

904b3fe78a64        zeppelin            "bin/zeppelin.sh"        2

> hours ago         Up About an hour    127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp
>   zeppelin

0a07c4e94350        cassandra:3.0

> "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours
>   7000-7001/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9042->9042/tcp, 7199/tcp,
>   127.0.0.1:9160->9160/tcp   myCassandra PS D:_GDrive__dockerShipyards_>
>
> **TESTING CASSANDRA :** 
>        D:_GDrive__dockerShipyards_>powershell -Command "& {docker run -it --name Cassinterface --link myCassandra:cassandra --network=flyingCassandra --rm cassandra:3.0 cqlsh cassandra;}"
>
> ```
> Connected to Test Cluster at cassandra:9042.
> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
> Use HELP for help.
> cqlsh> describe keyspaces
>
> system_traces  system_schema  system_auth  system  system_distributed
>
> cqlsh> describe cluster
>
> Cluster: Test Cluster
> Partitioner: Murmur3Partitioner
>
> cqlsh>
> ```
>
> Cassandra works fine.
>
> _____________ Zeppelin interpreter settings :  (host is 172.18.0.3 , port is 9042 , protocol v4)
>
> ### https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymi56.jpg
>
> result : [enter image description here][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38OMh.png